# Numbering Theorems by Subsections

Tags: sectioning, numbering, lyx, theorems, coding

I want to make my theorems to be numbered by subsection, for example after subsection 4.1 I want the next theorem to be numbered as 4.1.1 but instead I get the numbering only by the section itself. Is there a way to change that in the settings only and without having to write any code? I'm a maths student, I have no clue about how and where and why to write a code in lyx, I just want to know if there's a simple solution in the settings of lyx to change that, as all the information I could find about it included coding and wasn't helpful for me.

Thanks a lot and sorry for the "non-coding" trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE....

As you are not provided any `MWE`, I assumed that you are using the standard supporting files, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\numberwithin{theorem}{subsection}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using  `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]` would be a simpler code, in my opinion.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, but I believe that my suggestion will reset the counter by every `subsection` bu auto...Also suggest, shall I change my post per your opinion?

Comment: Your post is useful because it draws the attention to the \counterwithin command, and not all declarations have the possibility to use the simpler syntax. Maybe add the other construct as a note?